# How do I disable the "code not covered" glyphs in the OpenCover UI extension for Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, opencover

I would file a bug report but it seems like such an obvious piece of functionality that I must be missing something...

These are the glyphs that appear in the editor window in the same bar as the breakpoints to indicate that a line of code was not covered by my unit tests.

I'd like to disable them temporarily since they cover up my breakpoints.

[Extension I'm talking about](https://github.com/OpenCoverUI)

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on menu `OpenCover -> OpenCover Results` will open a window (unless it is alrady open and docked somewhere)

In the top of this window, there are 3 menu buttons. The middle one enables\disables the glyphs (circles).

[image]